# How can I flex shrink image so as to fit all flex children within parents set height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to shrink the middle image (using flex-box) such that when the content in `header`, `footer` grows it shrinks such that the total content height of flex children (`header`, `footer`, `img-wrap`) does not overflow out of parent container?

**Current view of layout in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rseni/pen/ZEadayQ?editors=1100)**

[image: Current view of layout in CodePen]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .header,
.wrapper .footer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.img-wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 3;
  min-height: auto;
}

.img-wrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.footer .btn {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <h4>Box title</h4>
    <p>Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShS9EkKjqdM_u5LKC2rI_Utrc0lVvWy5-krg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <button class="btn">My button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the updates in the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .header,
.wrapper .footer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.img-wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 3;
  min-height: 0; /* 0 instead of auto */
}

.img-wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain; /* use object fit */
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.footer .btn {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <h4>Box title</h4>
    <p>Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShS9EkKjqdM_u5LKC2rI_Utrc0lVvWy5-krg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <button class="btn">My button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't often resort to absolute positioning, but it works here on the image container, which is now *inside* the flex child. Note that non-static positioning must be set on the parent element as well.

Also, instead of wrestling with `flex-grow` and `-shrink` values, I just use `flex: auto` and `flex: none` on the various flex children. It isn't necessary to use it in all cases, but it makes the layout's behavior more intuitive to me when I see it in the CSS.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper .header,
.wrapper .footer {
  flex: none;
}

.header {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-wrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.footer {
  flex: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.footer .btn {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <h4>Box title</h4>
    <p>Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShS9EkKjqdM_u5LKC2rI_Utrc0lVvWy5-krg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <button class="btn">My button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `display: grid` for this one.

Check the `object-fit: cover;` for the image so that it doesn't squeeze and with this solution, the image stays centered and isn't just cut below.

Does this work with my pen?
https://codepen.io/maki3000/pen/BamgxaB?editors=1100

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

p,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr minmax(10px, auto) 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.img-wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.footer .btn {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <h4>Box title</h4>
    <p>Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text Some blurb text </p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShS9EkKjqdM_u5LKC2rI_Utrc0lVvWy5-krg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <button class="btn">My button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: TBH, I was looking to solve this in `flex-box` context and the accepted answer did just that. Irrespective, this this is an excellent solution. Thanks much for your answer.